# Fragment tag using error in WordPress Gutenberg Block Development

Tags: wordpress, fragment, wordpress-gutenberg

I have used Fragment tag in my WordPress Gutenberg block development in my project. It's returning an error in my project. I can't understand what's wrong in my code. And how to solve it. When i am using as array. It's working fine.

This is my error message screenshot link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF7Gz.jpg

This is my code/plugin zip link:
https://github.com/Rayhanuc/elementorpagebuilder/releases/tag/1.0

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Before using this tag, you must assigned it:

```
const { Fragment } = wp.element;
```

Comment: Thank's for your Suggestion and help.